# How to develop the option to resize font in an android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I was wondering how to develop a bottom bar to show the option to increase/decrease the font size depending on user choice.

The thing is I've been thinking to create a layout (as a footer) to make it invisible at the beginning so when user touch the screen I'd like to show them that bottom layout with those options.Is that possible?

How can I do that?Mean that I've been thinking to use a EditText#getTextSize() and resize the font size every time user press the option. I am not sure if this is the proper way to develop something like that.

Would you mind to advice me how to do it?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what you mean by "bottom bar". do you mean menu? i would advice letting that be a menu option if possible. (also to just have +/- and maybe max/min options for font size. because letting user type in a font such as "32" may be bad if you don't check for things like "#$@2211")

i wouldn't recommend the invisible layout as that would just look visually empty and like it's missing something. (not all devices will have a default black background for apps, so the color might also not be fitting with your app)

```
//if regular font
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_textview_size_options);
tv.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size_regular));
```

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for your suggestion. However I wouldn't like to develop a menu because my aim is get something like an actionbar however the sdk I'm using is 8. The idea is to show that 'actionbar' when user touch screen also part of the content in that bar would be buttons to increase/decrease the size.Hopefully I've explained it properly. Cheers

Comment: @didilin gotcha. go ahead and give your idea a try :) then if the code doesn't work, you can ask it again on S.O. with the code